# How should you handle slow requests (image upload from mobile) on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have a server side API running on Heroku for one of my iOS apps, implemented as a Ruby Rack app (Sinatra). One of the main things the app does is upload images, which the API then processes for meta info like size and type and then stores in S3. What's the best way to handle this scenario on Heroku since these requests can be very slow as users can be on 3G (or worse)?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to upload the images directly to Amazon S3 and then have it ping you with the details of what was uploaded.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#file-uploads

Comment: Can it ping me with details such as image size and image type?